# Gravity Forms - gform_after_submission not working

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

gform_after_submission is getting called in my page, but the $entry and $form objects are null.  Is there any reason why that would be happening?  Based on the output of the logs, I know the code runs, but can't figure out why the $entry argument is null.

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_2', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2);
function post_to_third_party($entry, $form) {

   error_log("Posting comments form");

   $post_url = 'https://api.club-os.com/prospects?clubLocationId=686';
   $body = array(
    'first_name' => $entry['7.3'], 
    'last_name' => $entry['7.6'], 
    'email' => $entry['6'],
'mobilePhone' => $entry['8']
   ); 

   error_log('Before Post to' . $post_url);

   $args = array(
'headers' => array('Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'username' . ':' . 'password' )),
'body' => $body,
    'sslverify' => false
    );  

   foreach ($body as $key => $value) {
      error_log($value . " in " . $key . ", ");
   }

   $request = new WP_Http();
   $response = $request->post($post_url, $args);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

'first_name' => $entry['7.3'], 
   'last_name' => $entry['7.6'],

The 7.3 and 7.6 were incorrect indexes to the $entry object.  I just used '7' and the split function to get it to work correctly.